# How can I get the most recent rows from two different, unrelated tables, and merge them into one result set?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two different tables with their schema given below:

Table1:

```
COLUMN_NAME     COLUMN_TYPE

campaign_id     varchar(50)
subscriber_id   varchar(50)
message         varchar(21000)
log_time        datetime
log_type        varchar(50)
level           varchar(50)
campaign_name   varchar(500)
```

Table2:

```
COLUMN_NAME      COLUMN_TYPE

guid             varchar(100)
sid              varchar(100)
url              varchar(2500)
ip               varchar(20)
is_new           varchar(20)
ref              varchar(2500)
user_agent       varchar(255)
stats_time       datetime
country          varchar(50)
region           varchar(50)
city             varchar(50)
city_lat_long    varchar(50)
email            varchar(100)
```

I need a table which is a merge of these two tables(not all the columns) and the rows should sorted based on time (which is log_time in Table1 and stats_time in Table2). There is no relation between these two tables.

The columns which I need from Table1 are

```
campaign_id
subscriber_id
message
log_time
log_type
campaign_name
```

and the columns which I need from Table2 are:

```
url
stats_time
email
```

Can I get more optimised solution?

Query:

```
SELECT url, ip, stats_time, email, campaign_id, subscriber_id, campaign_name, log_time, log_type, time from
(  
( SELECT url,ip,stats_time,email,NULL AS campaign_id,NULL AS subscriber_id ,NULL AS campaign_name,NULL AS log_time,NULL AS log_type, NULL AS message, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(stats_time) AS time FROM Tabel2 AS Table2Alias WHERE URL !='' AND EMAIL != '') Order by stats_time desc Limit 100

UNION ALL  

( SELECT NULL AS url,NULL AS ip,NULL AS stats_time,NULL AS email,campaign_id,subscriber_id,campaign_name,log_time,log_type,message,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(log_time) AS time FROM Table1 AS Table1Alias WHERE (log_type='x1' OR log_type='x2' OR log_type='x3' OR log_type='x4') order by log_time desc Limit 100)
)
as ResultTable order by time  desc
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be quicker to union them first and then sort by time once?

Comment: No. The tables are too big. And there is a scroll down function which triggers this query with offset and limit. So merging two tables each time  whenever there is a scroll is not quick.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? What information are you trying to extract?

Comment: I need the recent 20 rows from these two tables. They don't have anything thing in common. But there is a time column through which I can get the recent 20 rows.

Comment: If you only want the 20 most recent rows from the combination of tables, then why do you have them return 100 rows each with the `LIMIT`? If you only need 20 total, you'd only need 20 from each, and then you can select the 20 most recent from those 40 results.

Comment: I don't need the rows from combination. I need the top 20 rows after the union of these two tables

Comment: If you need the top 20 rows, then you cannot possibly need 100 rows from each table. You need the 20 most recent from each table, then union those results together, and the 20 most recent from the union. 

If you only need 20 rows from a union of the two tables why would you ever get 100 rows from each? The max number of rows it needs from either table is 20... It's just common sense.

Answer (score 0):

Select the top `Limit + Offset` records from each table, UNION the results, then select from the UNION.

So if user is viewing page 5, and there are 20 items per page, you will be selecting top 100 from each table, performing UNION, then selecting 20 records from result.

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudocode for you -

```
 SELECT 
     /* columns you want */ 
 FROM 
     (
         SELECT 
             /* columns you want */
         FROM
             /* Table1 */ 
         ORDER BY 
             /* Date DESC */
         LIMIT 20 

         UNION ALL 

         SELECT 
             /* columns you want */
         FROM
             /* Table2 */ 
         ORDER BY 
             /* Date DESC */
         LIMIT 20 
    ) 
ORDER BY 
     /* Date DESC */
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Hi,

This query will not work for one scenario. 

If table1 has 60 rows on today's date and table 2 has 20 rows on yesterday, this query will give the result set of rows which will have table2  rows too. This shouldn't be the result because all the top 20 rows should be from table1 as they are the most recent.

Comment: Have you tried this and found that was the case? 

I assure you, it would not include any from `table2`. `ORDER BY /* Date DESC */` following by `LIMIT 20` means that it will only take the 'top' 20 in the list after they have been ordered. So, if the 20 from `table1` are all more recent than the 20 from `table2`, it will only show the `table1` rows...